# How to create JCheckBox for elements of an ArrayList

Tags: java, checkbox, arraylist

I have an array that fills in by the user. Then each element of this array will be a CheckBox. For example if the array has 6 elements, it must create 6 checkboxes.

This is how I tried to loop through the array and create the checkbox, but it only overwrite on one checkbox.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Options");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setSize(300, 300);

    ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myArrayList.add("checkbox 1"); 
    myArrayList.add("checkbox 2");
    myArrayList.add("checkbox 3");
    myArrayList.add("checkbox 4");
    myArrayList.add("checkbox 5");

    for(String element : myArrayList){
        JCheckBox box  = new JCheckBox(element);
        frame.add(box);
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

It is important that I have the access to each single checkbox later, so I can specify for example `if checkbox2 is selected, do this`.

So is there any way to make these checkboxes dynamically according to the ArrayList's size?

Comment: Create another ArrayList, and use it to store references to the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you add something new to the JFrame, it removes the thing that was previously in it.

You'll need to create a JPanel or some other container to hold the JCheckBoxes, and then put that inside the JFrame.

Also, you can keep track of the checkboxes in a List.

For instance:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, panel));
List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();

for(String element : myArrayList) {
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(element);
    checkboxes.add(box);
    panel.add(box);
}

frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Seems working. Only two things. The line `List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();` Comes up with an error: _type List does not take parameteres_. And also can you give an example of accessing one of this checkboxes? something like `checkbox2.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: @dan You want to import "java.util.List" and not "java.awt.List"; you can access elements from a List using its get method. I suggest you take look at [the Collections trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, you're adding all the check boxes to the same location on the frame.

A `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default. A `BorderLayout` allows a single component to be managed in each of its five available slots. Basically a `BorderLayout` will ignore all but the last component added to any of the slots

Instead, try changing the `LayoutManager` to something more useful, like `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` depending on your needs

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) for more details.

Depending on your needs, I might be tempered to fill the `ArrayList` with the `JCheckBoxes` instead of `String` or even a `Map` of some kind, to make it easier to link the text with the `JCheckBox`